# Java File IO performance?

Tags: java, performance, io, nfs

I am using RandomAccesFile and writing data in chunks of 10MB at a time. Following is source. Here it is writing 10MB data in write call. It's taking ~700ms. Is there any way to improve this using file channel or some other means. FileSystem is NFS.

```
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(randomAccessFile.getChannel());
            randomAccessFile.seek(offset);

        output.write(data, 0, dataLength);//10MB
        output.flush();
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: 10 MiB in less than a second is reasonable, honestly; don't forget that you have to go over the network and networking overhead is not negligible. The major performance boost you can gain here is by inspecting and modifying if necessary the configuration of your NFS server/client.

Comment: You could compress your data

Comment: It's servlet which reads POST data in chunks of 10MB and save to file. Data is read into chunks to retry file operation if it fails.

Comment: `randomAccessFile` cannot be null at the point you are testing it. You should write directly using the `RandomAccessFile` and get rid of the `Channels` and `OutputStream` stuff altogether.

Answer (score 1):

NFS is, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), nonlocal so you're pretty much limited to your network bandwidth - being able to write 10MiB in 700ms is equal to having a bandwidth of 14,28 MiB/s - that'd be about 119Mbit so im guessing you were actually talking about MB/s in which case you still had 114Mbit .... well, i will assume you're on Gigabit-LAN.

In that case, you indeed would have some performance issues because gbit-LAN can do much more than that. There are several steps to find the root cause :

- check if another application is running
- check if your NIC has some faulty settings (reset to factory default if possible)
- check if another application is able to transfer data faster than that

and finally (if the problem persists):

- switch to Java NIO and see if it makes your situation better, here are a few examples : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/example/